# DJango fill existing formset from View

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I understand that you can fill a form from a view with:

```
initial_data = { 'box0': 'X', 'box1': 'O', 'box2': 'X' }
form = myform(initial=initial_data)
```

But, how do you do it for a formset?  The below causes error **"TypeError: formset_factory() got an unexpected keyword argument 'initial'"**

```
initial_data = []
for i in range(rowCount):
    xy = getRandomXY(3)
    initial_data.append({
        'box0': xy[0],
        'box1': xy[1],
        'box2': xy[2]
    })
formSet = formset_factory(myform, extra=rowCount, max_num=10, initial=initial_data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initial is not a parameter of form_factory. It should go inside Formset. Check out [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/formsets/#using-initial-data-with-a-formset) for detail.

```
formSet = formset_factory(myform, extra=2, max_num=10)
forms = formSet(initial=data)
```